# Pull data from Website into VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This might fall under the dumb question from a newbie. But I honestly don't know where to start in VBA. I tried a few different approaches on the web trying to pull data from the site I'm trying to and all of them failed miserably. Can someone help me (more or less show me) how to pull the data from this website?

https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl?site=fanduel

It wouldn't even let me do the data->import. here is what I have so far. I keep getting stuck on line For t = 0 To (Table.Length - 1).

```
Sub test1()
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Dim Table As Object
Dim t As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl?site=fanduel"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Table = appIE.document.getElementById("proj-stats")
For t = 0 To (Table.Length - 1)
    For r = 0 To (Table(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (Table(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = Table(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Look what I have above. Am i close? @portlandrunner

Comment: There are loads of browser plugins that will allow you to export a table from a webpage, maybe try one of those to see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, and there are several ways to get the data.  I chose to extract all row elements (HTML `<TD>`) and step through a simple loop.  Since there are six columns I'm using two variables (`r` & `c` for row and column) to offset the data to format correctly.

```
Set Table = appIE.document.getElementsbytagname("td")
r = 0
c = 0

For Each itm In Table
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = itm.innertext
    c = c + 1
    If c Mod 6 = 0 Then
        r = r + 1
        c = 0
    End If
Next itm
```

---

Example Result:

[image]

---

One last note, sometimes the browser didn't finish loading before the script went on... I cheated by using a break point before the loop, waited until it loaded, then hit F5 to continue execution of code to ensure it would alway run.

Comment: Thank you! I have it running smoothly now.